# Loadin images to scrollview in another thread still makes scroller stack

Tags: objective-c

I have a `scrollView`, which i load images into while scrolling, means when user scroll to some page `X`,  i load only images at  `x-4 < images < x+4` ,so at any given moment i have only this 8 images in memory .

Now each image on the scroller, is created with 2 layers , one is some blur effect, and above it the real image . i creates them using async method ,to not disturb the scroll .

Problem is that scroller is not scrolling fluently . here is the loader method, happens when user done scrolling to some page :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^
                   {
                       NSData *imdata2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                        {

                          UIImage *theImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imdata2 scale:1];
                          UIImage *blurImage = [theImage applyLightEffect];

                          imageResizer *resizer=[[imageResizer alloc] init];
                          UIImage *scaledImage =[resizer resizeImageToWidth:[Globals sharedGlobals].imagesWidth WithImage:theImage];

                          CGRect viewSizeBack=CGRectMake(scroller.bounds.size.width*toPage , 0, scroller.bounds.size.width, scroller.bounds.size.height);

                          int x=[Globals sharedGlobals].pageMargins;
                          int y=[Globals sharedGlobals].bottomLine-scaledImage.size.height;


                          CGRect viewSizeFront=CGRectMake(x , y, scaledImage.size.width,scaledImage.size.height);




                          UIImageView *backImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewSizeBack];
                          UIImageView *frontImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:viewSizeFront];



                          backImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
                          backImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
                          backImageView.image=blurImage;

                          frontImageView.layer.cornerRadius = [Globals sharedGlobals].cornerRadiuses;
                          frontImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
                          frontImageView.image=scaledImage;

                          [backImageView addSubview:frontImageView];

                          backImageView.tag=toPage;
                          frontImageView.tag=toPage;
                          [scroller addSubview:backImageView];


                        });
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved ,
Seems that i had to take out to another thread also the resizing of the images , not only the creating of the `NSData` , so :

```
 NSData *imdata2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                       UIImage *theImage=[UIImage imageWithData:imdata2 scale:1];
                       UIImage *blurImage = [theImage applyLightEffect];
```

makes everything works great .